# Connecting to ACCESS on network (HOMEGROUP)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, network-programming

I have 2 machines: ROY-PC running Windows 7 and MSI running Windows 10.
I have ACCESS and Visual Studio 15 on both machines.
The DB I'm trying to connect to is on ROY-PC.
I can access the DB using ACCESS on MSI.
The following is the code I am using to connect:

```
CatalogProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
CatalogFile = "\\ROY-PC\Users\Public\Documents\FMN.accdb"
CatalogConnectionString = CatalogProvider & CatalogFile
CatalogConnection.ConnectionString = CatalogConnectionString

Try
    CatalogConnection.Open()
    Mainfrm.ShowDialog()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Can't open DB")
End Try
```

The code runs fine on ROY-PC but throws an error when I run it on MSI.

Ideas?

Comment: OK. The error is "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered on the local machine". And yet the project compiles and runs on the local machine (MSI).

Comment: A quick Google found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb). Not sure if you have already tried this.

Comment: So you can connect to it directly from MSI, and compile and run it within the IDE on MSI, but when you try to run the standalone exe on MSI (from the Debug or Release folders?), it gives you that exception?